# Smart contract deployment in testnet not starting in truffle

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, truffle

I am trying to deploy a smart contract in truffle. But after i run the command in terminal my smart contract gets compiled and nothing happens after that. I Deployed using the command

```
truffle deploy --network ropsten --reset
```

Please find truffle config file.

```
require('dotenv').config()
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
var mnemonic = process.env["MNEMONIC"];
var endKey = process.env["INFURA_API_KEY"];
module.exports = {
networks: {
development: {
host: "127.0.0.1",
port: 7545,
network_id: "*" // Match any network id
},
ropsten: {
provider: () => new 
HDWalletProvider(mnemonic,"https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/" + endKey),
port: 7545,
gas: 3000000,
network_id: 3
},
rinkeby: {
provider: () => new 
HDWalletProvider(mnemonic,"https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/" + endKey),
port: 7545,
gas: 3000000,
network_id: 4
}
},
};
```

Please find the migration file below

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./NewGame.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

Its showing

> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile

Comment: Show your truffle config file and migration file.

Comment: Hi @ZulhilmiZainudin I have attached the files.

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced some problems with the truffle migration/deploy --reset option on older versions of truffle.

Try upgrading your truffle to the latest version, if that doesn't work try cleaning up build/contracts/* directory and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the port on which ganache is running  whether it is 7545 or 8545 or 9545. Anf then set your truffle config file accordingly. Also check your contract version as well as compiler version